# Minimal subgroups lie in the center so group is nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of **odd** order. If every minimal subgroup lies in the center, prove that $G$ is  nilpotent . Thanks!

Comment: Do you know things like Thompson's AxB lemma? (In general, it is a good idea to describe what you have tried, even if it doesn't work. It makes it easier to tell what will help you.)

Comment: (I ask because this is exactly suited to theorem 5.3.10 in Gorenstein's Finite Groups, page 184. However, my proof uses p-nilpotence, transfer and all sorts of crazy things. Maybe there is a much easier way. :-)

Comment: Your proof is the best. you see better  and easy. one proof i see in the Huppert  but is not easy. can you tell me hot answer ?

Comment: This is Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen* Satz III.5.3.a on page 283. The local version is Satz IV.5.5. The local implies the global, but Huppert uses the global to prove the local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ an odd prime, such that every subgroup of order $p$ is contained in the center of $G$. Then $G$ is $p$-nilpotent.

**Corollary**: If $G$ has odd order and every subgroup of prime order is central, then $G$ is nilpotent.

**Lemma:** (Thompson) If $P \leq G$ is a $p$-group for $p$ an odd prime, and $Q \leq N_G(P)$ is a subgroup whose order is relatively prime to $p$, and $Q$ centralizes every element of $P$ of order $p$, then $Q$ centralizes $P$.

*Proof:* See [Gorenstein's Finite Groups theorem 5.3.10, page 184](http://books.google.com/books?id=5gRFNiMjUqwC&lpg=PA184). $\square$

*Proof:* (of the proposition) Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and let $x \in N_G(P)$ have order relatively prime to $p$. Since every subgroup of order $p$ is central, $x$ centralizes every element of order $p$, and thus by the lemma, $x \in C_G(P)$. Hence $[N_G(P):C_G(P)]$ is a power of $p$. By Frobenius's normal $p$-complement theorem ([Theorem 7.4.5, page 253](http://books.google.com/books?id=5gRFNiMjUqwC&lpg=PA253)), $G$ is $p$-nilpotent. $\square$

*Proof:* (of the corollary) Such a group is $p$-nilpotent for every odd prime $p$ by the proposition. Since the group itself has odd order, it is $p$-nilpotent for every prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$. Hence the group is nilpotent (the intersection of the normal Sylow $q$-complements for $q \neq p$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup). $\square$

Comment: Sorry if this is not any better. I'll go check Huppert and see if I get any bright ideas.

Comment: This Huppert's Satz IV.5.5 on page 435. Instead of using Thompson's lemma, he uses an analysis of minimal non p-nilpotent groups. I'm still reading to see if I can find any great ideas.

Comment: you are very brilliant man. tank you Bertram_Huppert_Endliche_Gruppen_I__1967 page 283 (5.3 satz)     I have one question aboout Schmidt group ? I write in the web

Comment: I have to run, I'll take a look at it later today. :-)

Comment: tank you my dear.                       http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414225/schmidt-group-and-maximal-subgroup

Comment: You did the best as ALWAYS, Jack. (+100k) @JackSchmidt

Answer (score 2):

This is more like Huppert's proof, which is mostly on the bottom of page 434 to the top of page 435 (and then maybe in a previous chapter?)

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ an odd prime, such that every subgroup of order $p$ is contained in the center of $G$. Then $G$ is $p$-nilpotent.

**Corollary**: If $G$ has odd order and every subgroup of prime order is central, then $G$ is nilpotent.

*Proof:* (of proposition) Let $G$ be a minimal counterexample. Every subgroup of $G$ still satisfies the hypothesis (that all elements of order p are central). Hence every proper subgroup is $p$-nilpotent, by induction. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $N_G(P)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then it is $p$-nilpotent. That is, $N_G(P) = P \ltimes Q$ with $Q$ a normal Sylow $p$-complement. However, $Q \leq N_G(P)$, so we get that both $P$ and $Q$ are normal in $N_G(P)$ and $N_G(P) = Q \times P$ so that $Q \leq C_G(P)$. [Note how we've recovered part of the Thompson lemma.]

... Now we prove $P$ has exponent $p$. ... [eek time to go]

Since every element of $P$ has order (dividing) $p$, we see that $P \leq Z(G)$, so that by Schur-Zassenhaus $G= Q \times P$ (for a slightly bigger $Q$, a Sylow $p$-complement of $G$). $\square$

Comment: The ... follows from Satz III.5.2.c but requires quite a lot of work. Hence this answer is not very helpful for the original question.